# (Word Press) Ultimate Member Plugin: Update labels in Login page

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm using Ultimate Member WordPress plugin. 
I want to change the text “forgot your password” to “비밀번호찾기” (Korean) and "Keep me signed in" to "로그인상태유지" (Korean) in the Login page.

But, I can't find "forgot your password" and "Keep me signed in" in the plugin editor.

Can anyone tell me where do I change the text? 
Or Is there any other way?

[sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ifdnt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Loco [Translate plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/)

install it and search for the strings you want to change

or if you prefer not to install a plugin, i recommend [Poedit](https://poedit.net/)

Loco Translate is easier to use, so if you're new to wordpress use the plguin